# Exception Removing PDF Page on Itext7

Tags: itext7

According to the itext website this is the process for submitting a bug report?

Anyways with certain PDF files (not all) I will see this exception calling the removepage function on the document in **Itext V7.1.1.0**

If I swallow the exception it seems to remove the page and produce a valid PDF file.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutline..ctor(String title, PdfDictionary content, PdfOutline parent)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.ConstructOutlines(PdfDictionary outlineRoot, IDictionary`2 names)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.GetOutlines(Boolean updateOutlines)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.RemoveOutlines(PdfPage page)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.RemovePage(Int32 pageNum)
```

Comment: Please share a sample PDF for which the exception occurs.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to do this it contains confidential information.

Comment: In that case your issue can hardly be verified let alone analysed.

Comment: You're welcome ?